# Using FFmpeg AutoGen save to bitmap works on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, gdi+, gdi, system.drawing, autogen

I'm using FFmpeg.AutoGen to decrypt video and save the frames as bitmaps. Code is using dotnet core and I'd like to get it working for both Windows and Linux.

The code is similar to the example provided: https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/blob/db9bcd4b9dfad5d117ffd71fe1a2d073e96a3520/FFmpeg.AutoGen.Example/Program.cs

```
AVFrame convertedFrame = this.converter.Convert(frame);
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(convertedFrame.width, convertedFrame.height, convertedFrame.linesize[0], PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, (IntPtr)convertedFrame.data[0]);
```

When saving the image using:

```
image.Save($"returned-image-{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.png", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

The image looks fine on Windows, but is corrupted in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use different version of FFmpeg libraries. Also check the latest Open issue from FFmpeg.Autogen, might be that.

Comment: thanks, I have tried the different versions of FFmpeg 4.x with the related package from Autogen. They all work on Windows but have the same issue on Linux. I also looked at the Open issues before posting this question, but didn't see anything.